# ejabberd mod_pubsub offline message

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ejabberd

I want to intercept the offline message of `mod_pubsub`, if I send a normal message in ejabberd to offline user, I see that message in offline odbc table, if user reconnect the message arrive.

If I publish to a node, and some user are offline, I see nothing in offline message table, but if the user reconnect the item node is sent correctly so the message is saved somewhere.

Can I send the item offline to offline message odbc table? or can I intercept the offline item of `mod_pubsub` like for message, in fact for message from plugin I can do this:

```
 start(_Host, _Opt) ->
    inets:start(),
    ejabberd_hooks:add(offline_message_hook, _Host, ?MODULE, create_message, 50).

 stop (_Host) ->
    ejabberd_hooks:delete(offline_message_hook, _Host, ?MODULE, create_message, 50).
```

this is my `ejabberd.yml` config for `mod_pubsub`:

```
mod_pubsub:
  access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
  ## reduces resource comsumption, but XEP incompliant
  ignore_pep_from_offline: true
  ## XEP compliant, but increases resource comsumption
  ## ignore_pep_from_offline: false
  last_item_cache: false
  db_type: odbc
  plugins:
    - "flat"
    - "hometree"
    - "pep" # pep requires mod_caps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As default, pubsub message type are `headline`. As per XMPP specifications, headline messages should not stored in offline message store.

However, there is a `mod_pubsub` option to change default notification type. You can for example set `mod_pubsub` `notification_type` option to `normal`. Normal messages are store in offline store.